# How to remove Recaptcha from Firebase Phone Verification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I used Firebase auth with Play Integrity to verify user's phone number and added Sha-values in Firebase console. When send a verification code to users, it first redirect to a robot check page before they sent the code to the users but it is a bad user experience. Is there a way to verify the phone without recaptcha? I tried Twilio but their price is kinda expensive.